# What are the major regional French accents, together with a well known exponent of them?

Tags: accents-régionaux

In English, the major accent varieties that people are familiar with would be Cockney (Michael Caine), Essex/estuary English (people on TOWIE), Geordie (Sarah Millican), Liverpudlian/Scouse (members of The Beatles, Alexei Sayle), Mancunian (Noel Gallagher), and so on.

Could anyone give a similar list for French accents with well known exponents, to make it easy to search Youtube for an interview or something similar?

Comment: In British English, that is. Let's not forget there's a few people living on the other side of the Atlantic, too. HAPPY FOURTH OF JULY!

Comment: @Aerovistae My significant other also objected to my not listing any Irish accents!

Comment: @Lambie If you can find a list in one place in the format of qoba's answer, or jiliagre's with the names of famous speakers who are easily youtube'd with copious results, I'd be grateful if you could pass it on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- accent marseillais : Fernandel, Éric Cantona
- accent toulousain : Claude Nougaro (merci @Laure)
- accent provençal : Charles Pasqua
- accent du Nord : les Fatals Picards, les personnages de *Bienvenue chez les Ch'tis*
- accent parisien : Jean Yanne
- accent lyonnais : Alexandre Astier
- accent "versaillais" (en fait, accent bourgeois de tout l'ouest parisien) : Valérie Lemercier jouant Béatrice de Montmirail dans les *Visiteurs*
- accents basque, auvergnat, alsacien, lorrain, montbéliard, savoyard : pas d'idée mais ce sont des accents bien distincts, il y a des vidéos indexées par ces termes sur YouTube

Notes :

- Certains locuteurs (c'est mon cas, et, dans mon expérience, plus souvent le cas pour les accents autres que ceux du Sud et de Paris) tendent à diminuer leur accent régional au profit d'un accent plus "neutre" dès qu'ils se trouvent dans un contexte professionnel. Cela peut rendre difficile l'observation de certains accents dans des entretiens. Les documentaires type "fly-on-the-wall" comme l'émission de télévision *Striptease* peuvent fournir des exemples plus authentiques.
- Il y a un continuum d'accents, pas forcément des catégories très bien définies. Par exemple les habitants du midi peuvent percevoir fortement les distinctions entre différents accents dits "du sud", d'autres par exemple venant d'autres régions ne les perçoivent pas.

Comment: Merci, en cherchant vos termes sur YouTube j'ai trouvé ce video "Les journaux régionaux", avec les accents (satirique) de Marseille, Alsace, Corse, Bretagne, Savoie, Pays Basque, Nord Pas-De-Calais : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtKT2ETxwcc

Comment: À rectifier accent du midi par accent Marseillais. Il y a beaucoup accents « du midi » aussi différents les uns des autres que, par exemple, l'accent Alsacien et l'accent du Nord. Les accents de Toulouse, Bordeaux,  Marseille, de l'Auvergne sont autant d'accents différents caractéristiques. Et les gens du sud-ouest eux-mêmes distinguent sans hésiter accent toulousain, Ariégeois, etc...

Comment: C'est vrai, corrigé

Comment: @criollo Ces sketchs des *Inconnus* ont eu un certain succès dans les années 90, mais ce sont des caricatures simplifiées voire erronées, faites par des comédiens qui n'ont pas réellement l'accent. Je ne les recommande pas comme source de documentation authentique. J'ai amendé la réponse pour indiquer que des documentaires pourraient être plus intéressants.

Comment: Merci @qoba. En fait, en général j'ai du mal à différencier entre plusieurs sortes d'accents de la France metropolitaine. Peut-être les exagérations comiques peuvent au moins mettre en valeur les éléments les plus distinctives pour m'aider commencer à les différencier...

Comment: L'accent stéphanois (De Saint Etienne) est assez typique également (en tout cas très différent de Lyon et Valence). France Inter a fait [une émission sur les accents régionaux](https://www.franceinter.fr/emissions/un-jour-en-france/un-jour-en-france-11-avril-2016) et les stéphanois avaient une place à part.

Comment: @qoba n'est pas toulousain ça c'est sûr ;-) un toulousain aurait mis en premier l'accent toulousain en premier en citant l'enfant du pays Claude Nougaro. Qu'on peut entendre dans des interviews conservées [sur son site](http://www.nougaro.com/), dans [ses chansons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xpge7PshQT8). À écouter aussi [Le véritable accent de Toulouse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIuTXcuiIUI).

Comment: @Laure ajouté Toulouse et Nougaro merci. Jylo j'ai indiqué le stéphanois dans ma réponse juste pour donner un exemple pour illustrer que s'agissant d'un continuum, il était difficile de catégoriser de manière définitive les accents régionaux. J'ai pris un autre exemple plus radical pour illustrer. criollo en fait ce qu'il te faudrait peut-être pour t'aider dans cet objectif ce serait (outre des exemples) la liste des caractéristiques différenciantes de ces accents.

Comment: @criollo Le Ministère de la culture a un site [*Le corpus de la parole*](http://corpusdelaparole.huma-num.fr/spip.php) qui permet de faire des recherches par langue de France et/ou par accent. Accéder directement [à la recherche](http://corpusdelaparole.huma-num.fr/spip.php?rubrique3). Le site rame un peu en ce moment, mais on y arrive quand même.

Comment: L'accent de Charles Pasqua, né à Grasse dans les Alpes-Maritimes, n'était pas du tout corse mais provencal. L'accent corse (le vrai, qui tend à s'estomper comme tous les accents régionaux en France) est très différent de l'accent « du midi ».

Comment: Je rajouterais que « l'accent » Parisien (ou son absence, c'est une question de point de vue) est considéré normalement comme l'accent "de base", "neutre". En Bretagne, il est très proche (pratiquement similaire). Pour en revenir à la question, doit-on rajouter les tics de langages comme faisant parti de l'accent ? (Les fameux "y" par exemple qui peuvent perturber une personne apprenant l'anglais)...

Comment: L'accent antillais me semble lui aussi assez typique. En Belgique: accent liégeois, accent bruxellois, accent namurois, accent du borinage, accent du tournaisi.

Comment: @jlliagre bien vu, changé pour provençal

Comment: @Larme celui de Jean Yanne (parisien populaire) n'est pas vraiment neutre. Je n'ai pas ajouté les variations régionales de langage car ce n'était pas vraiment la question.

Comment: Montbéliard serait l'accent Franc-Comtois, si l'idée est de tracer des grandes zones.

Answer (score 9):

Regional and ethnic French accents are:

- The standard French, which you'll heard in national TV and radio channels and massively adopted by most formerly Langue d'oïl inhabitants who naively think is accentless.
- The southern accent, spanning the former Langue d'oc area and often called, *du midi* or *méridional* which has very specific differences with the standard French accent that are shared by all variants (provençal, marseillais, languedocien, toulousain, gascon but not auvergnat or limousin). This accent is also found in non occitan areas like the Pays Basque and Roussillon (Catalonia).
- The Alsacian accent, obviously in Alsace, which sounds similar to French ears to the German accent, not a surprise given the fact the vernacular language is Germanic.
- The Corsican accent which is quickly fading out. It is rarer now to find young people in Corsica with a "pure" Corsican accent as it is often some mixture of *méridional* and *corsican* accents nowadays.
- A large family of accents in the *Franco-Provençal* area, including the Dauphiné, Lyonnais, Savoyard, Suisse romande, Franche-Compté, Val d'Aoste (Italy), Forez where an accent can still be strong, especially in the rural places.
- The Mosellan accent, which slightly also sounds Germanic, especially with the tonical accent placed differently than in standard French.
- The Picard accent, commonly known as chti(mi), where *la* and *le* are not distinguished (*ferme la porte* → *ferme eul'porte*)
- The Belgian accents, which like all accents have several variants, not to be confused with the accents Dutch speaking Belgians have when they speak French.
- Various accents that only survive in rural areas in Brittany, Normandy, Burgundy, Champagne, Berri, ...
- *Antillais* accents (Guadeloupe/Martinique/Haiti/Guyane in the Caribeean)
- *Polynesien* and *Melanesien* accents (Tahiti, New Caledonia, ...)
- *Réunionnais* in La Réunion island
- *Québecois*, *Acadien*, *Cajun* and others, in Canada and some US states.
- *African* accents, in former French and Belgian colonies in subsaharan Africa.
- *Maghrebian* or *Arabic* accent, in Marocco, Algeria and Tunisia.
- *Pied-Noir* accent, fading out, from the European and other ascent people having left the Maghreb countries in the early sixties.
- *Banlieues* accent, which is a mixture of various accents from immigrates ascent people but with its own specificities, especially in its rhythm.
- *Asiatic* accent(s), essentially from people with their roots in what used to be the  French Indochina, especially Viet-Nam.

---

Note: There is no comparison between the high variation and the vitality of English accents and the French accents reality.

There is only one standard accent that every public person will use when talking to a public (radio, television, cinema, theater, meeting, stage.) If not the case, at best they will surprise the audience and at worst they will endure jeering and teasing.

Only the southern accent (i.e. *du midi*) manages to somewhat escape this pattern thanks to its friendly and jovial aspect, but even it its case, outside sportcasters where this accent is common, there was only Charles Pasqua, and Jean-Michel Aphatie today as examples of public people with a strong accent. I recently heard a customer of mine saying that our Prime minister Jean Castex accent, though only light in my opinion, was "pas sérieux", i.e. a bit ridiculous and not fitting for the job. That says a lot about the glottophobia of some French people.

The slow but steady homogenization of French pronunciation results in a lost of specificities by all the regional accents used in everyday life by French inhabitants.

This fact is very noticeable when comparing random people interviewed in the street today to similar situations during the sixties from TV archives.

When most of the accent is lost to conform to the standard, some specificities might remain like the open o's inside words (e.g. *rose* → /ʁoz/ vs /ʁɔzə/) or the differentiation between *in* and *un*.

---

Note : Il n'y a pas de comparaison entre la grande variété et la vivacité des accents en anglais et la réalité des accents en France.

Il n'existe qu'un seul accent « standard » que tout personnage public va utiliser quand il s'exprime publiquement (radio, télévision, cinéma, théâtre, discours, scène). Si ce n'est pas le cas, il suscitera au mieux la surprise et au pire railleries et quolibets.

Il n'y a guère que l'accent « du midi » qui arrive, grâce à son côté « sympathique », à partiellement échapper à cet état de fait, et encore, en dehors des journalistes sportifs où cet accent est très présent, il n'y a guère eu que Charles Pasqua et aujourd'hui Jean-Michel Aphatie comme exemples de personnes connues à l'accent prononcé. J'ai entendu récemment quelqu'un de mon entourage professionnel dire que l'accent du premier ministre Jean Castex, qui pourtant n'est pas si prononcé que ça, ne faisait pas "sérieux". Ça en dit long sur la glottophobie de certains français.

L'uniformisation lente mais régulière de la prononciation du français fait que les accents régionaux utilisés dans la vie de tous les jours par les habitants des différentes régions perdent eux aussi peu à peu leurs spécificités.

Ce phénomène est très perceptible quand on compare les interviews d'inconnus effectués aujourd'hui à ceux provenant d'archives de la radio ou la télévision effectués dans les années 50 et 60.

Quand l'essentiel de l'accent a disparu pour se conformer au standard, quelques spécificités subsistent parfois comme l'ouverture des *o* à l'intérieur des mots (ex : *rose* → /ʁoz/ vs /ʁɔzə/) ou la distinction entre *in* et *un*.

Comment: Merci du complément. C'est intéressant qu'il se soit créé dans le même temps un accent dit de banlieue.

Comment: Oui, je vais bientôt éditer ma réponse pour en faire justement une vraie réponse, et en évoquant aussi l'accent des banlieues.

Comment: "African accent" est plutôt vague, non ? Je sais généralement repérer si quelqu'un est kinois, rwandais ou de la campagne congolaise à l'accent et je ne doute pas que des distinctions plus fines soient possibles pour qui est en contact plus fréquent avec d'autres variétés africaines. Un pluriel serait à tout le moyen approprié. Idem pour les accents d'Asie du Sud-est

Comment: @Eauquidort J'ai corrigé mais tous les accents sont à la fois singuliers et pluriels. Quand on est pas spécialiste, tous les accents de ces pays se ressemblent mais sont bien identifiés comme spécifiquement africains. Les accents vietnamiens, laotiens et cambodgiens, bien que différents, sont assimilés à un seul accent pour le néophyte alors qu'un corse pourra sans doute distinguer l'accent d'un bastiais de celui d'un ajaccien. Même l'accent marseillais est composé d'une mosaïque d'accents variés au contour flou, l'origine sociale, l'histoire personnelle de chaque locuteur influence son accent

Comment: Là du coup j'ai un peu honte de ma réponse... Peut-être ajouter l'accent suisse ? Aussi d'accord sur la perte de vitalité des accents régionaux mais seulement dans le cadre du "pays" France -- les québécois ne normalisent pas ou en tout cas pas sur le même accent, ni les belges, suisses, ouest-africains, etc.

Comment: L'accent « suisse » est déjà dans ma réponse (Aire Franco-provençale). Les accents régionaux se standardisent aussi beaucoup en Suisse, Belgique, il suffit de comparer les journaux télévisés actuels et ceux d'il y a une quarantaine d'années. Au Québec et en Afrique, c'est moins c'est flagrant mais par exemple, on roule beaucoup moins les *r* au Québec depuis les années 60 / 70. La situation africaine est plus complexe car même là où il est la seule langue officielle ou une langue co-officielle, les français y est le plus souvent en concurrence avec des langues maternelles locales.

Comment: « c'est moins c'est flagrant »  → « c'est moins flagrant »

Comment: Nouvelle Calédonie, Les Seychelles, Tahiti, L'isle Maurice, par exemple. "African accent(s), in former French and Belgian colonies in subtropical Africa." You mean: sub-Saharan Africa, perhaps.

Comment: @Lambie J'ai déjà cité ces accents. Afrique subsaharienne, pas subtropicale, c'est exact.